# jQuery Tree drag drop - determine position after move

Tags: c#, jqtree

I am using jQuery tree to display a drag-drop structure. How can I determine where a node was moved? I need to keep the order of the nodes.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using jQTree? You need to detect the new position?

Comment: yes, exactly. I saw there is the event.move_info.position, but I need to know the same level order. for example if a parent node already has 2 children and you move your node as the first child, I need to change the order of the following 2